# Find the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos nx}{n!}$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Find the sums of the series:
>   $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos nx}{n!},\ \ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx}{n!}
> $$

I did something like this:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos nx}{n!}+i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(\cos x+i\sin x)^n}{n!}=e^{\cos x +i\sin x}-1=\\
&=e^{\cos x}\cdot e^{i\sin x}-1=e^{\cos x}(\cos(\sin x)+i\sin(\sin x))-1\Rightarrow\\
&\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos nx}{n!}=e^{\cos x}\cos(\sin x)-1,\ \ 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx}{n!}=e^{\cos x}\sin(\sin x)
\end{aligned}
$$
However, the answer section says that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos nx}{n!}=e^{\cos x}\cos(\sin x)$, and I have no idea where the number $1$ got from there.

Comment: If summation starts at $n=1$ then your result is correct (as you can see by setting $x=0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct. The problem is probably a misprint.

Comment: Thank you for your approval!

Answer (score 1):

Just check the two answers when $x=0$. You will see that the given answer is wrong. Your answer is the right one.